# How to use animations imported with the mesh from blender

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, blender

i have made an animation in blender with a mesh and a armature, i exported it as a FBX, and imported it into unity, i can see the animation and the mesh and it all looks fine, but since im only a few weeks into unity i dont know how to play, stop, rewind the animation and so on, i looked around for guides on how to do it and every video seems to make the animations inside of unity and use a character controller, did i screw up? do i have to make my animation and model all over again? whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the import options and check "import animations". you can also select if animations should be centered or relative.
also, I am pretty sure you will need an animation controller. a simple one will be sufficient.
altough I just googled your problem and found this answer that I cannot verify now but maybe its suitable to you:

> if you want to just play a clip on a thing, you can use the new
> Playables system, if you're in 2017.1 or later. The API is pretty low
> level, so you're going to want to wrap it in a component, but it's
> very ideal for "play a clip on a thing" situations. It's still using
> an animator to play the animation, but you don't need an
> AnimatorController, and you can dispose of the graph and stop the
> thing from doing stuff when it's not animating.

source: https://forum.unity.com/threads/playing-animationclips-without-an-animator.497400/

Comment: ok, thanks! ill check out the source and let you know if it lines up with my problem

Comment: alright i looked into it, your answer definitely helped me but now i have a new issue, i cant seem to get my animations to play, im using the play event on the animator controller under my model, and using animator.enabled = false to stop it, but the animation does not play, help?

Comment: find the name of the sequence and play it after you enabled animator again like this:
animator.Play("NameOfSequence");